# When will a C++11 compiler make RVO and NRVO outperform move semantics and const reference binding?

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the case when "whole" objects with move semantics enabled are returned from functions, as with `std::basic_string<>`:

```
std::wstring build_report() const
{
    std::wstring report;
    ...

    return report;
}
```

Can I then realistically be expected to make the "best" choice whether to use the returned string with move semantics, as in

```
const std::wstring report(std::move(build_report()));
```

or if I should rely on (N)RVO to take place with

```
const std::wstring report(build_report());
```

or even bind a const reference to the temporary with

```
const std::wstring& report(build_report());
```

**What scheme is there to make a deterministic choice of these options, if any?**

**EDIT 1:** Note that the usage of `std::wstring` above is just an example of a move semantics enabled type. It just as well be swapped for your `arbitrary_large_structure`.  :-)

**EDIT 2:** I checked the generated assembly when running a speed-optmized release build in VS 2010 of the following:

```
std::wstring build_report(const std::wstring& title, const std::wstring& content)
{
    std::wstring report;
    report.append(title);
    report.append(content);

    return report;
}

const std::wstring title1(L"title1");
const std::wstring content1(L"content1");

const std::wstring title2(L"title2");
const std::wstring content2(L"content2");

const std::wstring title3(L"title3");
const std::wstring content3(L"content3");

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const std::wstring  report1(std::move(build_report(title1, content1)));
    const std::wstring  report2(build_report(title2, content2));
    const std::wstring& report3(build_report(title3, content3));

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

The 2 most interesting outcomes:

- Explicitly calling `std::move` for `report1` to use the move constructor **triples** the instruction count.
- As noted by James McNellis in [his answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531700/when-will-a-c0x-compiler-make-rvo-and-nrvo-outperform-move-semantics-and-const/6531758#6531758), `report2` and `report3` does indeed generate identical assembly with 3 times fewer instructions than explicitly calling `std::move`.

Comment: I think it is _really_ weird that the call to `move` is not inlined and eliminated.

Comment: @James: Yes, especially in the light of Kerrek SB's comment that STL said RVO happens *before* anything else. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531700/when-will-a-c0x-compiler-make-rvo-and-nrvo-outperform-move-semantics-and-const/6533181#6533181) You're not by any chance located close to STL so that you can walk over and ask him? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++0x rvalues and move semantics confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c0x-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion)

Comment: @Howard: While your answer to that question is very good, I think this question addresses a deeper issue.

Comment: I do spend a fair amount of time in the building where he works, yes :-)  I haven't actually met Mr. STL himself yet, though.  I will follow up with them with regard to why `std::move` is not inlined here, though; I really do find that puzzling.  I am on vacation through the end of next week, so it will be a couple weeks before I can get back to you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::move(build_report())` is wholly unnecessary:  `build_report()` is already an rvalue expression (it is a call of a function that returns an object by value), so the `std::wstring` move constructor will be used if it has one (it does).

Plus, when you return a local variable, it gets moved if it is of a type that has a move constructor, so no copies will be made, period.

There shouldn't be any functional difference between declaring `report` as an object or as a const-reference; in both cases you end up with an object (either the named `report` object or an unnamed object to which the `report` reference can be bound).

Comment: *The other two should be functionally identical in the presence of (N)RVO* - interesting. I haven't thought about that. I'll take a look at the generated assembly. I'll be back!

Comment: I edited that a bit:  there shouldn't ever be a difference between those two:  practically speaking, in both cases you have to have some object in the scope of `report`; the only "difference" is whether `report` is the name of the object or is a reference bound to that object... from a performance standpoint there should be no difference between the two.

Comment: Please see my **Edit 2** in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is standardized (as Nicol says, all optimizations are up to the compiler), but I heard [STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-4-of-n) talk about this and (at least in MSVC), RVO happens *before* anything else. So if there's a chance to apply RVO, then that'll happen without any action on your part. Second, when you return a temporary, you don't have to write `std::move` (I think this *is* actually in the standard), since the return value will implicitly be treated as an rvalue.

The upshot is: Don't second-guess the compiler, just write the most natural-looking code and it'll give you the best-possible result.

Comment: In my **Edit 2** one can see that explicitly calling `std::move` will even prevent (N)RVO altogether.

Comment: @Johann: Cool. I suppose that shows that RVO is only considered if you return the naked temporary directly. One more reason not to try to outsmart the language!

Answer (score 3):

> What scheme is there to make a deterministic choice of these options, if any?

There isn't one, and there never will be.

Compilers are not *required* to do optimizations of any kind. The only thing you can do for certain is compile some code and see what comes out the other end.

The most you will eventually get is a general heuristic, a community consensus where people say, "for most compilers, X seems to work fastest." But that's about it. And that will take *years* as compilers get up to speed with C++0x and implementations mature.