# c++11 constructor with variadic universal references and copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, c++14

How to declare copy constructor, if we have constructor with universal reference arguments, also?

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e0355d60297db57

```
struct Record{
    template<class ...Refs>
    explicit Record(Refs&&... refs){
        cout << "param ctr" << endl;
    }

    Record(const Record& other){     // never called
        cout << "copy ctr" << endl;
    }

    Record(Record&& other){         // never called
        cout << "move ctr" << endl;
    }    
};

int main() {
    Record rec("Hello");    
    Record rec2(rec);  // do "param ctr"

    return 0;
}
```

According to this constructor list of `std::tuple` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple [look case 3 and 8] this problem somehow solved in standard library... But I can't get through stl's code.

---

P.S. Question somewhat related to [C++ universal reference in constructor and return value optimization (rvo)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24925137/1559666)

P.P.S. For now, I just added additional first param `Record(call_constructor, Refs&&... refs)` for really EXPLICIT call. And I can manually detect if we have only one param and if it is `Record`, and than redirect call to copy ctr/param ctr, but.... I can't believe there is no standard way for this...

Comment: I cannot write a full answer, but this should help you https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/too-perfect-forwarding/ The basic idea is to use SFINAE.

Comment: @DanielJour this is somewhat similar to my P.P.S. section, but thx, I'm glad to know this is known problem...

Comment: For future proofing this question, it should be pointed out that *universal reference* will officially be termed *forwarding reference*. The proposal for that can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the forwarding reference is used with `Record&`.

So you may add an extra overload for `Record&` (to forward to copy constructor):

```
Record(Record& other) : Record(static_cast<const Record&>(other)) {}
```

or use sfinae on the one with forwarding reference.

Comment: Is there are any drawbacks (with manual `const_cast`)? And what about move ctr?

Comment: @tower120: removing `const` may be dangerous, the only side effect I see when adding `const` is to use an other overload (as here).

Comment: @tower120: The move constructor may already be called, you may add extra overload for `const Record&&`  if needed though.

Comment: "Btw, you may prefer to use static_cast to add const" - Why?

Comment: @tower120: see [const-cast-vs-static-cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402318/const-cast-vs-static-cast)

Comment: Well, then update the answer with more "safer" variant :)

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem**

When you call `Record rec2(rec);`, you have two viable constructors: your copy constructor `Record(Record const&)` and the variadic constructor with `Refs = {Record&}` which works out to `Record(Record&)`. The latter is a better candidate since it's a less *cv*-qualified reference, so it wins even if that's not what you want.

**The Solution**

You want to remove anything that *should* call the move or copy constructors from being a viable candidate for the variadic constructor. In plain English, if `Refs...` consists of a single type that is either a reference to, or just a plain value, of a type that derives from `Record` - we do NOT want to use the variadic constructor. It's important to include the derived case as well, since you would certainly expect `SpecialRecord sr; Record r(sr);` to call the copy constructor...

Since this comes up, it's useful to have as a type trait. The base case is that it's neither a copy or move:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_copy_or_move : std::false_type { };
```

We only have to specialize on a single type:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_copy_or_move<T, U>
: std::is_base_of<T, std::decay_t<U>>
{ }
```

And then we just have to replace our variadic constructor with this SFINAE'd alternative:

```
template <typename... Refs,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_copy_or_move<Record, Refs...>::value>
          >
Record(Refs&&...);
```

Now if the arguments are such that this *should* be a call to a copy or move constructor, the variadic constructor will no longer be viable.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad practice to overload on forwarding references (see *Effective modern C++*, Item 26). They tend to devour everything you pass to them due to overload resolution rules.

In your example, you're constructing a `Record` object out of a non-const `Record` object and that's why your copy ctor doesn't get executed. If you call it like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da27d318d65c1ed6)

```
Record rec2(const_cast<Record const&>(rec));
```

then it works as expected.

A solution is to do SFINAE on the constructor with the forwarding references and *disable* the case a copy ctor should be called; it becomes somewhat ugly to write though in the variadic case :

```
template <
    class Ref1, class ...Refs, 
    typename = typename std::enable_if <
        !std::is_same<Ref1, Record&>::value || sizeof...(Refs)
    >::type
>
explicit Record(Ref1&& ref, Refs&&... refs)
{
    cout << "param ctr" << endl;
}
```

Now calling

```
 Record rec2(rec); // calls copy ctor
```

dispatches to the copy constructor since the template can't be instantiated for `Record&`

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d830219fca7ebe4)</kbd>

---

If your find yourself doing this a lot (not recommended) you could remove some clutter by defining a type trait to do the SFINAE

```
template<class T1, class T2, class... Refs>
using no_copy_ctor = typename std::enable_if <
    !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value || sizeof...(Refs)>::type;
```

thus writing the above as

```
template<class Ref1, class ...Refs, typename = no_copy_ctor<Record&, Ref1, Refs...>>
explicit Record(Ref1&& ref, Refs&&... refs)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Comment: You have to (re)-implement the default constructor also with your SFINAE solution.

Comment: And the condition is in fact more complicated, you forget to check `sizeof...(Refs) == 0`

Comment: @Jarod42 You're assuming that OP wanted to use the variadic constructor as a zero argument constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 In `Record rec2(rec)` the size of `Refs` is in fact zero. Can you please elaborate on checking it ?

Comment: Current code of OP allows a zero argument constructor. it was just a note. easy to fix. :-)

Comment: For the size, I means that you forbid also `Record rec2(rec, foo);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Fixed, thnx for being thorough

Comment: `is_same` isn't a sufficient check. You'll still find yourself preferring the variadic constructor in cases where the copy/move ctor should be preferred.