# What is the best way to return string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

My question is simple: if I have some class Man and I want to define member function that returns man's name, which of the following two variants shall I prefer?

First:

```
string name();
```

Second:

```
void name(/* OUT */ string &name);
```

The first variant is kind of inefficient because it makes unnecessary copies (local variable -> return value -> variable in the left part of assignment).

The second variant looks pretty efficient but it makes me cry to write

```
string name;
john.name(name);
```

instead of simple

```
string name(john.name());
```

So, what variant shall I prefer and what is the proper trade-off between efficiency and convenience/readability?

Comment: Side note, as `name()` looks like a query make it `const`: `string name() const;`.

Comment: @hmjd Why the first `const`?   The returned object ends up belonging to the client, and he should be free to do with it what he wants.

Comment: @JamesKanze, that is not part of the signature but rather my comment, it is follwed by a ':'.

Comment: If it is just a simple getter accessing a corresponding member variable, a `const std::string&` might be an even better idea.

Comment: @hmjd Sorry, then.  In the font I'm using, the : doesn't show up very well at all.

Comment: @ChristianRau Not usually.  It introduces issues of lifetime of the reference, etc.  In a base class, it can create real problems for the derived class.  Unless you actually want to support client code referring to internal data (and are prepared to document the validity of such references), it's best to avoid returning a reference.  (If the documentation of the function doesn't specify the lifetime of the reference, then I would consider the code broken.)

Comment: One of the many questions on RVO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596183/is-rvo-return-value-optimization-guaranteed-for-all-objects-in-gcc-compilers

Comment: @hmjd Nice remark, I usually do so. Thanks :)

Comment: @ChristianRau Let it be `fullname()` function that sticks first name and last name together and returns the result.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a good question and the fact that you're asking it shows that you're paying attention to your code. However, the good news is that in this particular case, there's an easy way out.

The first, clean method is the correct way of doing it. [The compiler will eliminate unnecessary copies](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/), in most cases (usually where it makes sense).

EDIT (6/25/2016)

Unfortunately it seems that David Abaraham's site has been offline for a few years now and that article has been lost to the ethers (no archive.org copy available). I have taken the liberty of uploading my local copy as a PDF for archival purposes, and it [can be found here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/316704010/Want-Speed-Pass-by-Value).

Comment: Yeah, it's a very well-written post that really hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the article and was **extremely** confused but it really cleans things up. Now I have to clean up my _efficient_ code =)

Comment: Of course, I would always use the 'second variant' for very heavyweight variables. I feel like this method could even be self-commenting because a reader would assume the datatype is heavyweight. least, my opinion.

Comment: The article is about RVO, but it is worth mentioning that In C++11, no RVO is necessary, because move semantics will kick in.

Answer (score 27):

use the first variant:

```
string name();
```

The compiler will most likely optimize out any unnecessary copies. See [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

In C++11, move semantics means that you don't perform a full copy even if the compiler doesn't perform RVO. See [move semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_semantics#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).

Also bear in mind that if the alternative is

```
void name(std::string& s);
```

then you have to specify very clearly what can happen to `s` and what values it can have when passed to the function, and probably either do a lot of validity checking, or simply overwrite the input entirely.

Answer (score 9):

Since you want to create a getter for a field of your class, maybe you should go like that: `inline const std::string& name() const { return this->name; }`

Since the name is returned as a const reference, it won't be modified outside the class, also no copy will be created by returning the name.

After that, if you want to manipulate the name you will have to do a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It makes sense, but I considered some situation when name is computed inside the function, e.g. 'fullname()' function that returns the last name and first name stuck together.

Comment: Yes, in that case you will have to return the value, as a reference to a local variable won't be valid after returning from the function. An alternative to you problem would be to compute the fullname everytime the first name or last name are modified (you can do that in the `setName` or `setFirstName` methods) and store it in a fullname field. That way, you won't have to recompute the fullname everytime you call `fullname()`, you just have to return const reference to the fullname field (as written in my answer).

Answer (score 6):

I would go with the first. Return value optimization and C++11 will remove any copying overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Rule #1 of optimization: *Measure*, optimize, measure. Or, as Knuth said, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Unless you have a strong indication that simply returning `std::string` will significantly impact the performance of your software, just do so. If you can *measure* a significant impact, find the critical path, and optimize *that*. Don't make any funny, project-wide "optimizations" that likely result in little to no performance benefit, but negatively impact the readability, maintainability and robustness of your code.

Answer (score 2):

As we have move-semantics (in C++11), you can use this:

```
string name();
```

Even in C++03, this is almost  good, as the compiler might optimize this (*Search for Return Value Optimization*).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use first variant. Because this is simple getter method and such getter/setter approach is used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For systems without heap, i.e. small microcontrollers, it might be a good idea to return a struct containing a char array large enough for longest string.

```
// define a non-growable string type with adjustable size,
// similar to Turbo Pascal but (here) zero-terminated
template<unsigned N>struct String{  // see (A)
  char s[N];
};

// A function converting to binary
String<17>binaryStr(uint16_t n)   // see (B)
{
  String<17>buf;    // see (C)
  char*p=buf.s;
  uint16_t mask=0x8000;
  while (;mask!=1; mask>>=1) if (mask&n) break;
  while (;mask; mask>>=1) *p++ = mask&n ? '1' : '0';
  *p=0;
  return buf;    // see (C)
}

// Use it somewhere
printf("42 is 0b%s\n",binaryStr(42).s);  // see (D)
```

**A**: For plain C, define some strings with fixed lengths instead, as you have no templates.

**B**: Functions returning a struct get a hidden pointer to a caller-reserved stack space.
As would be the following declaration:

```
String<17>& binaryStr(String<17>&, uint16_t);
```

The resulting string cannot have more than 16 characters plus terminating '\0', therefore 17.

**C**: At return, the struct has to be delivered in one piece. Accessing the hidden parameter is usually impossible. (In MSVC, it is possible using **__$ReturnUdt**.) Therefore, you need a local copy of the same struct and fill it with your code. Modern compilers are smart enough to avoid the "move constructor" at return statement and indeed won't allocate local stack space for **buf**.

**D**: Using the return value requires attention, especially at printf() functions having ... ellipisis (variable argument list). As standard behaviour of C/C++ is copying structures, the compiler would not complain but copying all the characters onto the stack! Therefore, you have to get a pointer, here by accessing **.s**.
For more readability for C++ users, add

```
const char*c_str() const{return s;}
```

to the String<> class.

As net result, you have a function that really returns a string, and you neither have to cope with manual stack space reservation, nor using static char arrays, nor use heap. Gotcha, you have to pay attention to forward a pointer, not the struct, to ... parameters.