# Why does opencv use output parameters, rather than just returning the ouput?

Tags: c++, opencv

In c++ we can take input parameters and simply return the values to the calling function, but `opencv` functions take output parameters as function arguments. Are there any performance/interoperability reasons for this? If not, then what are the reasons for this decision?

```
Mat img = cv::resize(someMat, ...);
cv::resize(someMat, img, ...);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056801/efficiency-of-output-parameter-vs-return-value-on-the-stack-for-stl-data-structu (modulo this is no opencv, but only the implementers of opencv can know why they did it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiency of output parameter vs return value on the stack for stl data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056801/efficiency-of-output-parameter-vs-return-value-on-the-stack-for-stl-data-structu)

Comment: Before move semantics, it was more efficient to pass by reference, not so much now. Also, if they both have C and C++ libraries to keep up to date, it's probably easier for them to pass by argument in both places so the APIs look pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference, but I have already gone through this. It only addresses the problem in terms of efficiency. I am also interested in some design related reasons. I have changed the question slightly to account for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing API is better and faster. It allows not to allocate memory every time. [In cv::resize](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp#L3740) for dst Mat will call cv::Mat::create. But if dst already has the same size and type then it will be [without new allocation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L828).

For example I can create image 800x600 and for big video file do resizing each frame into this buffer:

```
cv::Mat img(800, 600,...); // Initialization and memory allocation
...
for (; cap >> someMat;)
{
    cv::resize(someMat, img, ...); // No memory allocation, resizing into img
}
```

For this case it will be N memory allocations:

```
cv::Mat img;
for (; cap >> someMat;)
{
    img = cv::resize(someMat, ...); // New allocation inside cv::resize and free previous value
}
```

Comment: No, correct. I added links to the implementation of cv::resize and cv::Mat::create. The first case allows reuse memory. And the second - no: in cv::resize will create new cv::Mat dst.

Comment: Thankx for the great answer !! Are there any interoperability reasons for using this convention? I read somewhere that we can pass multiple types of containers in opencv functions like vector or Mat because these functions are just taking interfaces (e.g, InputArray) as input.

Comment: For std::vector will be the same behavior: if size() == newSize then vector.resize() will returns without reallocation.