# Return type of reference and copying object

Tags: c++, string, copy

If I return a std::string& from a function, and the return type is the rvalue of an assignment, I get a warning message from GCC. Is this because passing by reference will not copy properly? The error states that I am passing a temporary value, which I am, because it will soon be removed from the stack.

Here is some code for your consideration: Is what I am going to do a problem?

```
const std::string& TranslationTable::EnglishTranslate()
{
    return "end";
}
```

And inside main:

```
std::string me;
me = EnglishTranslate();
```

Will the contents of the returned string copy correctly into `me`?

Comment: return a `const &` is a bad design

Comment: Unless you are returning a member variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of `const char` denoted by `"end"` is converted to a temporary object of type `std::string`. That temporary is destroyed as soon as `EnglishTranslate` returns. That leaves the returned reference dangling, not pointing at a valid object.

Passing that returned reference to the copy assignment operator of `me` will result in undefined behaviour (assuming the operator is defined to do what it should do).

I recommend returning by value instead:

```
std::string TranslationTable::EnglishTranslate()
{
    return "end";
}
```

Don't worry about the copy to the return value - the compiler is allowed to remove the copy entirely.

The only real common use for returning a reference from a function is to return a reference to a data member. A data member, unlike a local variable, is not going to be destroyed at the end of the function. See [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) for an example.

Comment: ... Or should I pass a std::string& as an argument and do the copy inside the functions?

Comment: @EdwardBird Return by value. Never return a reference to a temporary object.

Comment: @EdwardBird related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553091/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-string-in-c/10553140#10553140). This one is about the virtues of returning by value vs. passing a reference as function argument.

Answer (score 2):

> Is what I am going to do a problem?

**Yes.**

Per Paragraph 12.2/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; **the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement**.

Hence, the reference returned by your function is dangling, and you have **Undefined Behavior** when dereferencing it.

Comment: What is this book people keep referencing? Can I get a copy of it?

Comment: @EdwardBird: It is the C++11 Standard. You can download the original, but you have to pay for it. Or you can download the most recent draft for free from [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf).

Comment: @EdwardBird It's not a book. It's *the* C++ standard. It's the very definition of what C++ is.

Comment: @sftrabbit ... So where can I read/learn from this c++ standard? Or how?

Comment: @EdwardBird Andy Prowl just linked to the latest draft. Beware though - it's not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: @sftrabbit A few pages a night - I'll be done by the time the next draft is written.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Don't be so optimistic! ;-)