# Can I rely on named return value optimisation for complicated return types?

Tags: c++, rvo, nrvo

Consider something like this:

```
typedef std::unordered_multiset<int> Set;
typedef std::set<Set> SetOfSets;

SetOfSets somethingRecursive(SomeType somethingToAnalyze) {
    Set s;
    // ...
    // check base cases, reduce somethingToAnalyze, fill in s
    // ...
    SetOfSets ss = somethingRecursive(somethingToAnalyze);
    ss.insert(s);
    return ss;
}
```

This approach is fairly standard for problems like generating subsets, permutations, etc. However, I tried making a diagram of what exactly Return Value Optimization should optimize here given the fairly complex internal data structure of the type (`std::unordered_multiset` is a hash table and `std::set` is 'typically' a binary search tree) and, well, I can only hope that compilers are smarter than me.

So, talking performance and (in case it matters) `C++14`, can I return a `SetOfSets` here or should I just pass it by reference as an out parameter?

Comment: You aren't using RVO, but NRVO. The difference is subtle, but it's there :) People often put the later under the former, so yeah.

Comment: @Rakete1111 NRVO is a subset of RVO. It has a special name mostly just because various compilers implemented RVO for just rvalues first, and then the addition of NRVO was a big deal around 2003-ish.

Comment: I'd need to look into the C++17 requirements for a complete answer.  But classic NRVO doesn't care about how "complicated" the type is. A typical compiler just basically figures "the only return statement is `return ss;` and `ss` is a local non-static class-type variable, so instead of putting `ss` on my own stack space, I'll use the return address provided by the caller for it in the first place."

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm aware of this, thanks. :) Spent like 3 minutes deciding on what tag to add and went with this one since it's more popular. Let's see if someone more knowledgeable than me finds the difference important enough to edit my question.

Comment: I think this needs another go round the open-close cycle. NRVO is much trickier for compilers to spot and implement.

Comment: @Bathsheba Am I getting it right that if I avoid creating the named `ss` object here and just return `somethingRecursive(somethingToAnalyze).insert(s)`, optimization is guaranteed?

Comment: @sigil: Absolutely not. No optimisation is guaranteed until C++17. Although you could see what your particular compiler is doing by stepping through the program with your debugger or putting special messages into constructors.

Comment: Anyway, at worst, you will have a move construct of `SetOfSets` which is cheap.

Comment: @Bathsheba "No optimisation is guaranteed until C++17." - Okay, but at least it's not in any way related to type complexity, right? Or this is what https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596700/6885358 seems to be talking about at any rate.

Comment: @sigil: Who knows? The C++ standards are woolly on this up to and including C++14. So you need to make piecemeal tests and hope you're not using a capricious compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba "So you need to make piecemeal tests and hope you're not using a capricious compiler." - Grrr. Fine. I'm using an out parameter here. Ugly beats unpredictable. *stomps out angry

Comment: Everybody is saying that in C++17 RVO is mandatory, but nowhere can I find proposal [#P0135R0 Guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) having been merged into c++17.

Comment: @YSC Because, technically, it's not copy elision. In C++17, there is no temporary materialized, when prvalue is returned. Just the effect is "such as if RVO was applied, more or less". Note that this has consequences - you can return prvalue in C++17 even if neither copy nor move constructor exist (`std::atomic`).

Comment: @DanielLangr I've finished reading all parts of the standard implying RVO, you were right. I'd like to find the courage to make it a Q&A some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before C++17, you cannot rely on copy elision at all, since it is optional. However, all mainstream compilers will very likely apply it (e.g., GCC applies it even with `-O0` optimization flag, you need to explicitly disable copy elision by `-fno-elide-constructors` if you want to).

However, `std::set` supports move semantics, so even without NRVO, your code would be fine.

Note that in C++17, NRVO is optional as well. <s>RVO is mandatory.</s>

---

To be technically correct, IMO, there is no RVO in C++17, since when prvalue is returned, no temporary is materialized to be moved/copied from. The rules are kind of different, but the effect is more or less the same. Or, even stronger, since there is no need for copy/move constructor to return prvalue by value in C++17:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> f() {
  return std::atomic<int>{0};
}

int main() {
  std::atomic<int> i = f();
}
```

In C++14, this code does not compile.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision it is. But I haven't check the Standard, since don't have an access to the official (non-draft) version. In the latest draft, see 15.8.3(1.1).

Comment: @Bathsheba It's impossible to guarantee NRVO in the general case, because it's impossible to determine in the general case at object construction time whether the object will be used as the return value.

Comment: I am not a language lawyer, so technically, we maybe shouldn't talk about RVO in C++17. From Cppreference: _C++17 core language specification of prvalues and temporaries is fundamentally different from that of the earlier C++ revisions: there is no longer a temporary to copy/move from. Another way to describe C++17 mechanics is "unmaterialized value passing": prvalues are returned and used without ever materializing a temporary._ I use this term in the meaning of its effect. (Note that there is no RVO mentioned in C++11 Standard as well.)

Comment: @hvd IIRC, there are restrictions in earlier standards already, i.e. you cannot have multiple return statements that return different objects. The question was whether NRVO is guaranteed *in this case*, anyway, which is a very straightforward create-initialize-return pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> So, talking performance and (in case it matters) C++14, can I return a SetOfSets here or should I just pass it by reference as an out parameter?

If you use a decent compiler, you can safely return it by value as copy elision will occur. But. But copy elision is not guaranteed<sup>1</sup> and your compiler might do it only when the right optimization flags are given.

> #### [`[class.copy.elision]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.sentence-1)
>
> When certain criteria are met, an implementation **is allowed** to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects.

This means you should only rely on copy elision if your program still makes sense if it is not performed.

---

<sup>1)</sup> except for `constexpr` objects

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It is really common, though not guaranteed, so it all depends on your required confidence level.

AFAIK this description is up-to date and covers your topic [copy_elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

The key sentences are: "*Under the following circumstances,  **the compilers are permitted, but not required** to omit the copy- and move- construction of class objects even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects.*"

Then there is a description of NRVO (which you present). And, at the next bullet there is a description of **anonymous temporary RVO**, and a bullet that this one **is mandatory since c++17. Otherwise none are guaranteed.**

It doesn't matter how complicated type is<sup>†</sup>, whatever "*complicated*" means. Those optimization kick in based on the status of the variable e.g: "*a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be copied or moved into an object of the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification)*". Note that none of this related to the inner working of the type of variable<sup>†</sup>, but rather the context in which it is used.

What you can do, is to make a minimal example and put it through compiler and analyze assembly to see if the optimization kicked in, or [generate optimization report](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-emit-optimization-reports), and see yourself.

---

<sup>†</sup> The only reference is explicit statement that optimization is allowed for types with side-effects on construction and destruction. But this serves as exceptional enabling clause. For types with no side-effects those are already possible by default.