# Which function structure is better?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, nrvo

Look at the following code:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){}
    MyClass(MyClass &&){}
    MyClass(const MyClass &){}
};
MyClass f1(){
    MyClass &&o=MyClass();
    /*...*/
    return std::move(o);//or return static_cast<MyClass &&>(o);
}
MyClass f2(){
    MyClass o=MyClass();
    /*...*/
    return o;
}


int main(int, char **){
    auto a=f1();
    auto b=f2();
}
```

Function `f2` is the normal form of returning an object. [NRVO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) may apply and the additional copy constructor call could be avoid. `f1` is the new form that uses rvalue reference. For systems that do not support NRVO but support rvalue reference, the move constructor is called rather than copy constructor, which would be considered better in most of the cases.

The problem of `f1` is that: are there any compilers that support of NRVO in this case? It seems to be the better form in the future after all.

Comment: "For system that do not support NRVO but support rvalue reference" I strongly suspect that such a system does not actually exist. I'd like confirmation on this.

Comment: ooohhh... "Which is better?" - this is the question to decisively end all "Which is better, a or b?" questions, right??? (hint: choose a more descriptive title)

Comment: The designers of C++11 bent over backward to make the most obvious code also the best code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c0x-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion/4986802#4986802 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how current compilers (MSVC10 / gcc trunk) works :
Assuming MyClass is moveable

```
f1 : move   
f2 :   
worst case : move 
best case : NRVO
```

Assuming MyClass is not moveable :

```
f1 : copy    
f2 :    
worst case : copy    
best case : NRVO
```

So even if compilers get better and start doing NRVO for functions like f1, why bother complicate the code when f2 classical C++03 functions are already optimal ?

Answer (score 4):

> are there any compiler support of NRVO in this case?

Define "compiler support"?

What `f1` does is *completely destroy* the compiler's ability to optimize the copy of `MyClass`. Let's look at `f1` in detail

```
MyClass &&o=MyClass();
```

This creates a *temporary*, not a stack variable. Then that temporary is bound to an r-value reference called `o`, which extends the lifetime of the temporary to the end of the function.

```
return std::move(o); //or return static_cast<MyClass &&>(o);
```

This returns an r-value reference of a stack-bound r-value reference to a temporary. And since you're returning a value, not a reference, the compiler has to create a temporary from it.

The copy/move of the temporary into `a` will be elided. But you still created *two* temporaries (the original and the return value).

So `f1` does the following:

```
create temporary
copy/move from temporary to return value
elide copy/move from return value to `a`.
```

`f2` does:

```
create stack variable
elide copy/move from stack variable to `b`.
```

If NVRO doesn't exist, you have:

```
create stack variable
copy/move from stack variable to return value
elide copy/move from stack variable to `b`.
```

So, `f2` is *at worst* equal to `f1`. And more than likely, better.

Please stop trying to out-think the compiler. Just let copy elision do its job.

Comment: You are not right. I specified the return value is a MyClass object, so the compiler have to return a copy of the reference, rather than return a object reference to be destroyed shortly. My compiler clearly calls the move constructor in this case.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Fair enough. But that doesn't change the fact that you don't get anything from doing it. See my edit.