# Is it a good practice that declaring a function as BigStruct&& foo(...);

Tags: c++, rvalue

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }

    A(const A&)
    {
        cout << "A(const A&)" << endl;
    }

    A(A&&)
    {
        cout << "A(A&&)" << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A&)
    {
        cout << "A(const A&)" << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(A&&)
    {
        cout << "A(const A&&)" << endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout << "~A()" << endl;
    }
};

A&& f_1()
{
    A a;
    return static_cast<A&&>(a);
}

A f_2()
{
    A a;
    return static_cast<A&&>(a);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "f_1:" << endl;
    f_1();
    cout << "f_2:" << endl;
    f_2();
}
```

the output is:

```
f_1:
A()
~A()
f_2:
A()
A(A&&)
~A()
~A()
```

---

The sample code obviously indicates that f_1() is more efficient than f_2().

So, my question is:

Should we always declare a function as some_return_type&& f(...); instead of some_return_type f(...); ?

If the answer to my question is true, then another question follows:

There have been many many functions declared as some_return_type f(...); in the C++ world, should we change them to the modern form?

Comment: Did you compile it with `-Wall`? "warning: reference to local variable ‘a’ returned". That's in your `f_1` definition...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a good practice that declaring a function as BigStruct&& foo(…);

Horrible practice. As with *lvalue-references* what you are doing is returning a *reference* to a local object. By the time the caller receives the reference the referred object is already gone.

> There have been many many functions declared as some_return_type f(...); in the C++ world, should we change them to the modern form?

The modern form is the form in which they were already built (considering only return types). The standard was changed to make the common form more efficient, not to have everyone rewrite all their code.

Now there are non-modern versions out there, like `void f( type& t )` instead of `type f()` when `f` *creates* the object. Those we want to change to the modern form `type f()` as that provides a simpler interface to reason about and provide for simpler user code:

Users don't need to think whether the object is *modified* or *created*:

```
void read_input( std::vector<int>& );
```

Does that append or replace the vector?

And make caller code simpler:

```
auto read_input();
```

vs.

```
std::vector<int> v; 
read_input(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `f_2` you're preventing the compiler from applying [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). When you drop the cast, and compile with optimizations enabled, you'll find that it's just as efficient. There's absolutely no need for the cast-to-reference, it makes no sense in `f_2`.