# Should std::move be used in return-statements for effeciency?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I cannot figure out if the std::move in the following code does anything good or that it is completely wrong?
The class `Object` has both Move and Copy constructor defined.

**First: With Move:**

```
template<typename T> template <typename F> 
const Object<T> Object<T>::operator*(const F& rhs) const 
{
    return std::move(Object(*this) *= rhs);  // We end in move constructor
}
```

**Second: Without Move**:

```
template<typename T> template <typename F> 
const Object<T> Object<T>::operator*(const F& rhs) const 
{
    return Object(*this) *= rhs; // We end in copy constructor
}
```

The `*=` operator is defined as:

```
template<typename T> template<typename F>  
Object<T>& Object<T>::operator*=(const F& rhs) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension ; i++)
    {
        _inner[i] *= rhs;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here is the code i use to test it:

```
Object<double> test(4);
Object<double> test2(test * 4);
std::cout << test2; // works fine
```

**Result**
In the **first** case we end in the move constructor and in the **second** we end in the copy constructor.

In either case the code compiles.

**Is one more efficient than the other since I would assume it is faster to move the new object out instead of copying it out?**

**Additional info:** 
I use the following compiler: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

Comment: Don't return `const` values, don't explicitly `std::move` local variables / temporaries, it inhibits (N)RVO. Why not write your `operator*` as `Object tmp(*this); tmp *= rhs; return tmp;`? That way, the compilers sees you return a local variable and turns it into an rvalue automatically when `return`ing it.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion

Comment: I just tested without `const`, it doesn't change the situation, but i could understand from the answers that i need `std::move` as i return a `lvalue`. If on the other hand it were and `rvalue` i didn't need `std::move`. And lastly if i used a temporary variable it would automatically be moved out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is one more efficient than the other since I would assume it is faster to move the new object out instead of copying it out?

Yes, using `std::move` here will be more efficient, assuming the object has move semantics more efficient than copying.

Usually, when returning a temporary or a local variable, move semantics will be used automatically. However, in this case you're not directly returning the temporary, but rather the *lvalue* reference returned by `operator*=`. Since an *lvalue* won't be moved, you do need `std::move` in this case to turn it into an *rvalue*.

However, you should not return a `const` value, as this prevents the return value from being used to move-initialise (or move-assign to) another object. Your example will initialise `test2` by *copying* the return value, although that copy might be elided.

Alternatively, you could implement it using a local variable:

```
template<typename T> template <typename F> 
Object<T> Object<T>::operator*(const F& rhs) const 
{
    Object lhs(*this);
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Not only can the return value be moved, but the move itself can be elided.

Comment: I suspect RVO will take care of the lvalue case so it should be indistinguishable (with perhaps even a slight advantage for RVO over move). But your last example (local variable) settles it all anyway. +1

Comment: @syam: I'm fairly sure elision is only allowed when (directly) returning a temporary or a local automatic variable. Certainly, my compiler doesn't elide the copy when returning the *lvalue*.

Comment: Please also advise to return a *non-`const`* `Object<T>`, as that returned value will cause a copy rather than a move if it's used like `auto c = a * b;`

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, I just noticed the `const` and added some advise about not doing that. (I didn't notice it in my tests, since that copy can be elided).