# std::move in return statements

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvo

I've been paying close attention to the advice never to write `std::move` in a return statement, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473874/1958315). Except there are some edge cases, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16606193/1958315).

I believe the following is another simple example of where `std::move` may be worthwhile - did I miss something? But I'm not sure why, and will that change in a future C++?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
};

struct C
{
};

struct B
{
    B(const A&, const C&) { std::cout << "B was copied\n"; }
    B(A&&, C&&) { std::cout << "B was moved\n"; }
};

B f()
{
    A a;
    C c;
    //return {a, c}; // Gives "B was copied"
    return {std::move(a), std::move(c)}; // Gives "B was moved"
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't trying to force move the returned object, you are constructing it. It's not related to the advice.

Comment: Those different constructors don't have anything to do with `B` being moved or copied.

Comment: your code is quite different from a `return std::move(x);`. What you move here is actually rather unrelated to the return

Comment: It isn't `B` that is moved or copied, it is `A` and `C`. It is your texts that are incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return {std::move(a), std::move(c)}
```

is equivalent to

```
return B{std::move(a), std::move(c)}
```

You're basically invoking `B::B(A&&, C&&)` instead of the version taking `const&` references. This has nothing to do with moving a return value.

The return value of the function is the temporary instance of `B`, which is a *prvalue*. It C++17, it will benefit from [**"guaranteed copy elision"**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Before C++17, it will be RVOd or moved into its target.