# Return a move-only object from member function

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I'm having a difficult time with understand + use move semantics in C++. I have an object `Variable` implements move constructor and move assignment but no copy constructor and assignment. Generally copying a `Variable` makes no sense and I want to prohibit copying explicitly.

```
class Variable {
public:
    // ctod/dtor things
    Variable(Variable&&);
    Variable& operator =(Variable&&);
    // ...
};
```

The question is what is correct way of returning a `Variable` from a function?

```
Variable& UserObject::giveMeYourVariable() {
    // Calculate parameters
    Variable v(/* Some parameters */);
    return v; // <=== warning: reference to local variable 'v' returned
}
```

In another code:

```
UserObject x* = new UserObject;
Variable v = std::move(x->giveMeYourVariable())
```

Above code compiles with no error but a warning about returning a reference to local variable. Does this code leaks memory or cause undefined behavior or return a deleted reference? What am doing wrong?

**Update**
Return by value causes error while initializing a reference type (inside a code that is generated by a parser-generator):

```
Variable& tmp (this->a_function()); <<== error
```

The error says:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Variable&' \\
from an rvalue of type 'Variable'
```

**Update 2**
This issue is [reported](http://codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2013-July/003996.html) in XSD mailing list and will be [resolved](http://codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2013-July/004000.html) in next release.

Comment: Returning references to locals leads to undefined behaviour, whether you use move semantics or not. [Stop stealing hotel room keys!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Comment: I see. So what I gather is that it's not a good idea to implement move constructor without a copy constructor. Right?

Comment: That conclusion makes no sense. Why would you think so? (see `unique_ptr` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr for the textbook example of such a class).

Comment: That parser generator is broken.

Comment: I'm in a situation that have no control over a big part of my project's code that's generated by CodeSynthesis XSD. Somewhere in generated code, it tries to assign a local variable from the reference returned from a member function. I can choose type of returned value. The only solution looks provide a copy constructor.

Comment: That won't work either. The fact that the generated code makes a reference is what needs fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Your program invokes undefined behavior.
As the compiler already told you, the lifetime of your `Variable` object is limited to the function call and the reference you return is no longer valid after the call.

You can simply return your `Variable` object by value

`Variable UserObject::giveMeYourVariable() {`

and happily move it around.

Comment: Returning by value says: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'AIT::CSP::Variable&' from an rvalue of type 'AIT::CSP::Variable'`

Comment: Of course you cannot initialize a reference with the return value. In your example you moved the returned object into a new variable.  If you need a reference to your `Variable` you need to store it within your `UserObject`

Comment: Use a variable, not a reference, as target

Answer (score -3):

You should move twice and return Variable object by value:

```
#include <utility>

class Variable {
public:
    // ctod/dtor things
    Variable() {}
    Variable(Variable&&) {}
    Variable& operator =(Variable&&) {return *this;}
    // ...
};

Variable foo() {
    Variable v;
    return std::move(v);
}

int main() {
    Variable v = std::move(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

std::move just switch type from Variable to Variable&&, that allows to call constructor with move semantic

so:

first std::move allows to create temporary object for return

second std::mode allows to create Variable v

Comment: There is no need to call `std::move` in either case. The first one even inhibits copy elision (NRVO).

Comment: NRVO works just in simple cases (like my example) but does not work in non-trivial cases (when return value depends of branching: `if(g) return v1; return v2`), does it?

Comment: So? Why would you want to inhibit it? There is nothing to be gained from returning with `std::move`.

Comment: Hm. I experimented a little and realized that not completely understand this topic :)
I do not understand why I can return object without std::move even if copy constructor is private

Comment: It is confusing stuff at first. There is a good related SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to explanation!