# std::move calls the destructor unexpectedly

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have been trying to write a class that cannot be copied but can be moved, and that cannot be created except with named constructors. I achieved my goal with `namedConstructor3` below. However, I do not understand why `namedConstructor2` failed.

```
struct  A
{
    int a;

    //static A && namedConstructor1( int a_A )
    //{
    //  A d_A( a_A );
    //  return d_A;     // cannot convert from A to A&&
    //}

    static A && namedConstructor2( int a_A )
    {
        wcout << L"Named constructor 2\n";
        A d_A( a_A );
        return move( d_A );
    }

    static A namedConstructor3( int a_A )
    {
        wcout << L"Named constructor 3\n";
        A d_A( a_A );
        return move( d_A );
    }

    A( A && a_RHS ) : a( a_RHS.a )
    {
        a_RHS.a = 0;
        wcout << L"\tMoved: a = " << a << endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        wcout << L"\tObliterated: a = " << a << endl;
        a = -a;
    }

    A( const A & ) = delete;
    A & operator =( const A & ) = delete;

protected:
    A( int a_A = 0 ) : a( a_A )
    {
        wcout << L"\tCreated: a = " << a << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A d_A2 = A::namedConstructor2( 2 );
    A d_A3 = A::namedConstructor3( 3 );
    wcout << "Going out of scope\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Named constructor 2
        Created: a = 2
        Obliterated: a = 2
        Moved: a = -2
Named constructor 3
        Created: a = 3
        Moved: a = 3
        Obliterated: a = 0
Going out of scope
        Obliterated: a = 3
        Obliterated: a = -2
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is the destructor called before the move constructor in `namedConstructor2` as evidenced by the 3rd and 4th lines of the output?
2. Why is the destroyed data still available to the moved constructor (as evidenced by the 4th line of the output)?
3. Isn't `namedConstructor2` "more natural" than `namedConstructor3` in the sense that the signature of `std::move` leads me to think that the return value of `std::move` has "two &&"?

​​​​

```
template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t )
```

---

Compiled with VS2013u4.

---

**Edit**

Deduplicator's answer satisfies me. This edit is for completeness sake. The answer and the comments suggested that `namedConstructor3` was "sub-optimal". I added

```
static A namedConstructor4( int a_A )
{
    wcout << L"Named constructor 4\n";
    A d_A( a_A );
    return d_A;
}
```

to the class and `A d_A4 = A::namedConstructor4( 4 );` to the `main` function. The new output (when compiled in release mode, not in debug mode) shows that the optimal case does not even move the object:

```
Named constructor 2
        Created: a = 2
        Obliterated: a = 2
        Moved: a = -2
Named constructor 3
        Created: a = 3
        Moved: a = 3
        Obliterated: a = 0
Named constructor 4
        Created: a = 4
Going out of scope
        Obliterated: a = 4
        Obliterated: a = 3
        Obliterated: a = -2
```

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, since constructor "2" returns a reference to a non-static local variable.

Comment: @KerrekSB: but contructor 3 has the same type of variable, doesn't it? After all, their bodies are identical.

Comment: Their return-types aren't, which makes all the difference. Thus `namedConstructor1` errors out, while in `namedConstructor2` you lie to the compiler and get UB, and in `namedConstructor3` you just pessimize with `move`.

Comment: @Hector not quite, the return value is not a "local temporary" (well at least not local to your function but local to the caller)

Comment: Constructor 3 copies (or rather *moves*) the value of the local variable into the return value; the return value is a prvalue.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Moves, though not due to automatic deduction. Which means NRVO does not apply, and we get sub-optimal performance.

Comment: An rvalue reference is still a reference. If you understand why returning an lvalue reference to a function local object is bad, then you have the same thing going on in `namedConstructor2`, except for the additional `static_cast<A&&>` (i.e. `std::move`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: are you implying that the return value is another variable? PeterT's comment seems to imply that as well.

Comment: @Hector: The return value isn't a variable. It's just a value, specifically, it's the value of the function call expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move(lvalue or xvalue)` does not call a destructor.

It just changes the passed reference to an rvalue-reference, so move-semantics apply.

So, why is your local destroyed too early?
Simple, returning a reference to a local variable is UB:
[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218)

Going over your named constructors one-by-one:

1. `namedConstructor1` returns an rvalue-reference.
   But you try to return a local (which is an lvalue), and the compiler complains about that error.
2. `namedConstructor2` is in principle the same as `namedConstructor1`, but you added an explicit cast (in the form of `std::move`) from lvalue to rvalue-reference, which shuts the compiler up.
   Thus, you get UB for lying to the compiler, specifically the locals lifetime ends at the end of the function, before the returned rvalue-reference is used.
3. `namedConstructor3` is ok, though sub-optimal.
   You are using the rvalue-reference to initialize the return-value (which is *not* a reference).
   The sub-optimal part is due to that `std::move` disabling return-value-optimization, which would obviate the need for the implementation to actually move (or copy) in this case.

Comment: Hmm, is the act of returning itself UB, or is any attempt to use the returned reference UB?

Comment: @T.C.: Not *quite* sure. I *think* if you ignore the return-value, you *might* be ok.