# Returning by reference a member of a destroyed local variable

Tags: c++, function, reference

Can someone explain whether this is ok or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    ~A() {std::cout << "A destroyed.\n";}
    const std::vector<int>& getNumbers() const {return numbers;}
    std::vector<int> getNumbersByValue() const {return numbers;}
};

std::vector<int> foo() {
    A a;
    a.numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
//  return a.getNumbersByValue();  // This works of course.
    return a.getNumbers();  // Is this line wrong?
}

void useVector(std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i = 6; i <=10; i++)
    v.push_back(i);
}

int main() {
    auto v = foo();  // A destroyed.
    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';  // 1 2 3 4 5
    std::cout << '\n';

    useVector(v);
    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';  // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
}
```

Since `a` is destroyed in foo(), then a.numbers is destroyed too, right?  If foo() returns a copy of a.numbers, using `A::getNumbersByValue()`, then everything is fine.  But above I'm using `getNumbers()`, which returns it by reference.  The vector still survives after foo() ends.  So I pass the vector into the function `useVector` to see if it still survives, and it does.  So is everything ok here?

Comment: But `v` is a copy. So there's no problem. In any case, you're not returning a reference to a destroyed object anywhere.

Comment: @juanchopanza.  If I replace return std::make_pair(v, 'k'); with return std::make_pair(a.getNumbers(), 'k');, everything works fine too.

Comment: That's because it does the same thing essentially.

Comment: You would have problem with `std::vector<int>& foo()` (reference added).

Comment: I changed the question and got rid of std::pair altogether.  The above code is still fine?  It would only be a problem if foo() returns `std::vector<int>?` right?  Hence `A::getNumbersByValue()` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it is fine. To quote my previous comment, "you're not returning a reference to a destroyed object anywhere."

Comment: Ok, I got it now.  Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `foo` returns its return value by value (not by reference), `foo` makes a copy of the vector to return.  It copies from the reference it got back from `getNumbers` as part of the return *before* it destroys the local variable `a`, so at the time it makes the copy, the reference is still valid.

So this code is fine.

Comment: To add on, most compilers will do RVO and thus skip the copy all together. In cases where this is not possible, C++11 will use the move constructor. Yay!