# C++ randomly sample k numbers from range 0:n-1 (n > k) without replacement

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on porting a MATLAB simulation into C++. To do this, I am trying to replicate MATLAB's [randsample() function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html). I haven't figured out an efficient way to do this yet.

So I ask you all, how do I best randomly sample k numbers from a range 0:n-1 (for n > k) without replacement in C++?

I've considered the following pseudocode (inspired by the third example on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)), but I feel like it's a bit hacky:

```
initialize vect<int> v of size n
for i = 0 to n-1
    v[i] = i
shuffle v
return v[0 to k-1]
```

The drawback here is also the requirement to build a massive array first too. That seems like slow/clunky overkill.

I would love some direction here if you can help. I'm less interested in the theory (algorithms are interesting but not relevant to my needs now) than the best way to implement this in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You tagged this C++, but your code is pseudo-code. Which are you interested in?

Comment: Fair enough question. I'm interested in C++, but particularly worthwhile functions in C++ to do the dirty work. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and it seems like this is pretty basic stuff so I imagine there's stuff out there. I just can't find it or figure it out.

Comment: Algorithms are totally relevant to your needs now, that's exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: We can argue semantics if you want. Sure, you're right, I need an algorithm. What I meant by that comment is I don't care about the running time of the pseudo random number generators and stuff. I am looking for efficiency, yes. But I don't want to be wasting tons of memory building a length-10^6 array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an approach that doesn't require generating and shuffling a huge list, in case `N` is huge but `k` is not:

```
std::vector<int> pick(int N, int k) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::unordered_set<int> elems = pickSet(N, k, gen);

    // ok, now we have a set of k elements. but now
    // it's in a [unknown] deterministic order.
    // so we have to shuffle it:

    std::vector<int> result(elems.begin(), elems.end());
    std::shuffle(result.begin(), result.end(), gen);
    return result;
}
```

Now the naive approach of implementing `pickSet` is:

```
std::unordered_set<int> pickSet(int N, int k, std::mt19937& gen)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, N);
    std::unordered_set<int> elems;

    while (elems.size() < k) {
        elems.insert(dis(gen));
    }

    return elems;
}
```

But if `k` is large relative to `N`, this algorithm could lead to lots of collisions and could be pretty slow. We can do better by guaranteeing that we can add one element on each insertion (brought to you by [Robert Floyd](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2013/05/robert-floyds-tiny-and-beautiful.html)):

```
std::unordered_set<int> pickSet(int N, int k, std::mt19937& gen)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> elems;
    for (int r = N - k; r < N; ++r) {
        int v = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, r)(gen);

        // there are two cases.
        // v is not in candidates ==> add it
        // v is in candidates ==> well, r is definitely not, because
        // this is the first iteration in the loop that we could've
        // picked something that big.

        if (!elems.insert(v).second) {
            elems.insert(r);
        }   
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Comment: This answer looks awfully familiar. :P

Answer (score 5):

Bob Floyd created a random sample algorithm that uses sets. The intermediate structure size is proportional to the sample size you want to take.

It works by randomly generating K numbers and adding them to a set. If a generated number happens to already exist in the set, it places the value of a counter instead which is guaranteed to have not been seen yet. Thus it is guaranteed to run in linear time and does not require a large intermediate structure. It still has pretty good random distribution properties.

This code is basically lifted from Programming Pearls with some modifications to use more modern C++.

```
unordered_set<int> BobFloydAlgo(int sampleSize, int rangeUpperBound)
{
     unordered_set<int> sample;
     default_random_engine generator;

     for(int d = rangeUpperBound - sampleSize; d < rangeUpperBound; d++)
     {
           int t = uniform_int_distribution<>(0, d)(generator);
           if (sample.find(t) == sample.end() )
               sample.insert(t);
           else
               sample.insert(d);
     }
     return sample;
}
```

This code has not been tested.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986802/2069064) for why to avoid `return move(sample);`.

Comment: Could be optimized slightly by doing an insert and seeing if that failed instead of doing a find followed by an insert.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from C++17, there's a standard function for that: [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) in `<algorithm>` library. It is guaranteed to have linear time complexity.

Sample <sub>*(pun intended)*</sub> usage:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> population {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::vector<int> sample;
    std::sample(population.begin(), population.end(), 
                std::back_inserter(sample),
                5,
                std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    for(int i: sample)
        std::cout << i << " "; //prints 5 randomly chosen values from population vector
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in [Yksisarvinen
's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58196592/1358308), C++17 provides [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) in `<algorithm>` that should be useful.  Unfortunately its use of iterators makes working directly with integers awkward, i.e. not building a large temporary array/vector, and the only way I've got it working usefully was with lots of boilerplate code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

template<typename I>
class boxed_iterator {
    I i;

public:
    typedef I difference_type;
    typedef I value_type;
    typedef I pointer;
    typedef I reference;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    boxed_iterator(I i) : i{i} {}

    bool operator==(boxed_iterator<I> &other) { return i == other.i; }
    I operator-(boxed_iterator<I> &other) { return i - other.i; }
    I operator++() { return i++; }
    I operator*() { return i; }
};
```

Giving us something not too painful to use with `std::sample`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    auto rng = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};

    // sample five values without replacement from [1, 100]
    std::sample(
        boxed_iterator{1}, boxed_iterator{101},
        std::back_inserter(result), 5, rng);

    for (auto i : result) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

It would be nice if `boxed_iterator` wasn't needed, it would be great if somebody could show me how!

Answer (score 0):

Bob Floyds sampling is a good solution. [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) however might be a good option when k is on the same order of magnitude as N.

[image]

Reservoir sampling:

```
vector<size_t> reservoir_sample(const size_t& k,const size_t& N) {
  vector<size_t> sample;
  if (k==0) return sample;
  std::default_random_engine gen;
  size_t i;
  for (i=0;i!=k;++i) sample.push_back(i);
  for (;i<N;++i) {
    uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distr(0,i);
    if (distr(gen) > k) continue;
    distr = uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0,k-1);
    sample[distr(gen)]=i;
  }
  std::shuffle(sample.begin(),sample.end(),gen);
  return sample;
}
```

Bob Floyd sampling:

```
std::unordered_set<size_t> floyd_sample(const size_t& k,const size_t& N) {
  std::default_random_engine gen;
  // for the benchmark I used a faster hash table
  std::unordered_set<size_t> elems(k); //preallocation is good
  for (size_t r = N - k; r < N; ++r) {
    size_t v = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, r)(gen);
    if (!elems.insert(v).second) elems.insert(r);
  }
  return elems;
}
```

Incomplete shuffle sampling:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::vector;
using std::uniform_int_distribution;
using std::shuffle;
using std::cout;
using std::swap;

template<class iterator,class generator>
void inline shuffle(iterator beg,iterator unt,iterator end,generator gen){
  const size_t n = end-beg;
  for (;beg!=unt;++beg) {
    size_t i=end-beg;
    size_t r=uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0,i)(gen);
    swap(*beg,*(beg+r));
  }
}

template<class iterator>
vector<size_t> sample(const size_t& k,iterator beg,iterator end) {
  vector<size_t> sample(k);
  std::default_random_engine gen;
  if (k<(end-beg)/2) {
    shuffle(beg,beg+k,end,gen);
    for (size_t i=0;i!=k;(++i,++beg)) sample[i] = *beg;
  } else {
    const size_t l = end-beg-k;
    shuffle(beg,beg+l,end,gen);
    beg+=l;
    for (size_t i=0;i!=k;(++i,++beg)) sample[i] = *beg;
  }
  return sample;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
  vector<size_t> samples(std::stol(argv[2]));
  auto start = std::clock();
  std::iota(samples.begin(),samples.end(),0);
  sample(std::stol(argv[1]),samples.begin(),samples.end());
  cout << std::setw(12) << (std::clock()-start);
}
```

Some notes: std::shuffle always shuffles the whole range, but when you only need k items you can stop with the fisher-yates shuffle at the kth element, making it the fastest method when the set to be sampled from already exists.

Answer (score 0):

So this was a solution I came up with that will generate the samples in a random order, rather than in a deterministic manner that would need to be shuffled later:

```
vector<int> GenerateRandomSample(int range, int samples) {
  vector<int> solution; // Populated in the order that the numbers are generated in.
  vector<int> to_exclude; // Inserted into in sorted order.
  for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
    auto raw_rand = rand() % (range - to_exclude.size());
    // This part can be optimized as a binary search
    int offset = 0;
    while(offset < to_exclude.size() &&
        (raw_rand+offset) >= to_exclude[offset]) {
      ++offset;
    }
    // Alternatively substitute Binary Search to avoid linearly
    // searching for where to put the new element. Arguably not
    // actually a benefit.
    // int offset = ModifiedBinarySearch(to_exclude, raw_rand);

    int to_insert = (raw_rand + offset);
    to_exclude.insert(to_exclude.begin() + offset, to_insert);
    solution.push_back(to_insert);
  }  
  return solution;
}
```

I added an optional binary search for the location on where to insert the newly
generated random member, but after attempting to benchmark its execution over large ranges(N)/and sets (K) (done on codeinterview.io/), I have not found any significant benefit to doing so, over just linearly traversing and exiting early.

EDIT: After further extensive testing, I've found over a sufficiently large parameters: (eg. N = 1000, K = 500, TRIALS = 10000)
The binary search method does in fact offer a considerable improvement:
for the given parameters:
with binary search: ~2.7 seconds
with linear: ~5.1 seconds
deterministic (without shuffle as proposed by Barry in the accepted answer based on Robert Floyd): ~3.8 seconds

```
int ModifiedBinarySearch(const vector<int>& collection, int raw_rand) {
  int offset = 0;
  int beg = 0, end = collection.size() - 1;
  bool upper_range = 0;
  while (beg <= end) {
    offset = (beg + end) / 2;
    auto to_search_for = (raw_rand+offset);
    auto left = collection[offset];
    auto right = (offset+1 < collection.size() ?
        collection[offset+1] :
        collection[collection.size() - 1]);
    if ((raw_rand+offset) < left) {
      upper_range = false;
      end = offset - 1;
    } else if ((raw_rand+offset+1) >= right) {
      upper_range = true;
      beg = offset + 1;
    } else {
      upper_range = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  offset = ((beg + end) / 2)  + (upper_range ? 1 : 0);
  return offset;
}
```