# std::sample() with integer range

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, c++20

How can I pick multiple values randomly in any given integer range?
With `std::sample()`,
one possible implementation would be:

```
void Sample(
    int first, int last, std::vector<int> *out, std::size_t n, std::mt19937 *g)
{
    std::vector<int> in{};
    for (int i = first; i < last; ++i)
    {
        in.emplace_back(i);
    }

    std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(*out), n, *g);
}
```

But I'm hesitating because creating `in` vector seems redundant and impractical,
especially when `first` is 0 and `last` is very big number.
Is there any public implementation or library for this requirement? e.g.:

- `sample(int first, int last, ...)` or,
- `ranges::sample(int n, ...)`

Comment: I posted a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642371/1358308 that doesn't require building a (potentially large) intermediate container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++20 you can sample on [`iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view)

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

void Sample(
  int first, int last, std::vector<int> *out, std::size_t n, std::mt19937 *g) 
{
  std::ranges::sample(
    std::views::iota(first, last), std::back_inserter(*out), n, *g);  
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1czfrqjEM)

Note that the above does not work in libstdc++ because `ranges::sample` incorrectly uses the `std::sample`'s implementation. Since `iota_view`'s iterator only satisfies *`Cpp17InputIterator`*, `std::sample` requires that the output range must be a random access iterator, which is not the case for `back_inserter_iterator`.

The workaround is to pre-resize the `vector`.

```
void Sample(
  int first, int last, std::vector<int> *out, std::size_t n, std::mt19937 *g) 
{
  out->resize(n);
  std::ranges::sample(
    std::views::iota(first, last), out->begin(), n, *g);  
}
```

which works in [both libstdc++ and MSVC-STL](https://godbolt.org/z/vfree473n).

Comment: It's worth noting though, that [`std::ranges::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sample) *"is **stable** (preserves the relative order of the selected elements) only if `I` models `std::forward_iterator.`"*. This seems to cause an observable difference in the behaviors of libstdc++ and MSVC-STL: https://godbolt.org/z/fY1dn6zGb