# Initialize static std::map with non copyable value in a uniformed inline initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, static-initialization, noncopyable

I'd like to initialize a static `std::map` where the value is not copyable. I'll call my class **ValueClass**. **ValueClass** has an `std::unique_ptr` as private member and I even ensure that ValueClass is not copyable by extending `non_copyable` that looks like the following:

```
class non_copyable {
public:
    non_copyable() = default;
protected:
    virtual ~non_copyable() = default;
private:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
    non_copyable& operator=(const non_copyable&) = delete;
};
```

Now I'm trying to define a std::map using my class as value:

```
static std::map<int, ValueClass> value_classes = {
    {0, ValueClass()},
    {1, ValueClass() }
};
```

I get compilation error as `initializer_list` tries to copy this class.

I've tried to write my own `make_map` function whole this weekend during many hours to enable initialization without copying but I've failed. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902621/5433463), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213907/5433463) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916584/5433463) but none of them compile with Visual Studio 15.9.4.

How can I initialize static std::map where copy is not forced, and the initialization is uniformed in one function, using Visual Studio compiler?

**EDIT:**
Here is the simplified version of the real life scenario where I'm trying to get this working (forgive me for lack of naming convention and inconsistency for cases):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class non_copyable {
public:
    non_copyable() = default;
protected:
    virtual ~non_copyable() = default;
private:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
    non_copyable& operator=(const non_copyable&) = delete;
};

class InnerValueClass : public non_copyable
{
public:
    InnerValueClass(const int inner_number) : inner_number_(inner_number) {  }
private:
    int inner_number_;
};

class ValueClass : public non_copyable
{
public:
    ValueClass(const int number1) : number1_(number1) {  }
    ValueClass(const bool condition) : condition_(condition), inner_value_(
        std::make_unique<InnerValueClass>(5)) {  }
private:
    int number1_{};
    bool condition_{};
    std::unique_ptr<InnerValueClass> inner_value_{};
};

/* Inline initialization of std::map copies, this is for initialization of non-copy types*/
template <typename TKey, typename TNonCopyableValue>
class make_map_by_moving
{
    typedef std::map<TKey, TNonCopyableValue> map_type;
    map_type map_;
public:
    make_map_by_moving(const TKey& key, TNonCopyableValue&& val)
    {
        map_.emplace(key, std::move(val));
    }
    make_map_by_moving<TKey, TNonCopyableValue>& operator()(const TKey& key, TNonCopyableValue&& val)
    {
        map_.emplace(key, std::move(val));
        return *this;
    }
    operator const map_type&()
    {
        return map_;
    }
};

static std::map<int, ValueClass> map =
        make_map_by_moving<int, ValueClass>
                (1, ValueClass(5))
                (2, ValueClass(true));
/* It goes on like this for hundreds of lines, so I really appreciate any
solution that leave me with a clean initialization rather than calling
functions on std::map */

int main() { }
```

**Duplicate edit:** The solution provided in that question does not work the class structure I have. I'm also looking for a solution to fix `make_map_by_moving` function in other words an inline initialization, the answer provided there is an imperative solution with function calls.

Comment: Is this map meant to be editable at runtime after the first initialization? I do recall a proposal (or implementation even) for a global const structure that offers natural initialization and map-like performance

Comment: I found this link: https://blog.knatten.org/2018/10/05/why-you-cant-list-initialize-containers-of-non-copyable-types/ that may give you some insight!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this directly, because `initializer_list` has `const` backing for all of its elements - and they have to be copied from the initializer list into the container. That, obviously, requires copying. There's no way to emplace from an initializer list unfortunately.

In C++17, thanks to guaranteed copy elision, you can do this:

```
std::map<int, non_copyable> get() {
    std::map<int, non_copyable> m;
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple(0), std::tuple());
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple(1), std::tuple());
    return m;
}

std::map<int, non_copyable> value_classes = get();
```

This code performs no copies on `non_copyable`. We emplace construct inside of the `map`, and then beacuse `get()` is a prvalue, there is no copy/move from `get()` into `value_classes`. The `m` within `get()` *is* the object `value_classes`.

A slightly sneaker approach would be to abuse `try_emplace()` for this:

```
std::map<int, non_copyable> get() {
    std::map<int, non_copyable> m;
    m.try_emplace(0);
    m.try_emplace(1);
    return m;
}
```

[`try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) takes the key type by itself (so you can just pass an `int`) and then the arguments for the value for emplacing separately, which makes for a much less verbose way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Another way is to simply call `m[0]; m[1];`. It will emplace default-constructed objects. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at.

Comment: Why  `try_emplace` instead of simple old `emplace`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I realized that I was not clear in the question, I'm sorry for that. I don't want to leave the values to be defined later on, I'd like to define the values as well.  I've updated my question with the code showing the real scenario I'm having.

Comment: @U.Bulle Well, I don't know how you expect your `ValueClass(int, const InnerValueClass&)` constructor to work given that `InnerValueClass` isn't copyable - but besides that, this answer provides a path to provide arbitrary constructor arguments just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to create the object with `insert_or_assign` in a function and then return it:

```
std::map<int, ValueClass> populate()
{
    std::map<int, ValueClass> value_classes;
    value_classes.insert_or_assign(std::make_pair(0, ValueClass());
    return value_classes;
}
```

And your initialization becomes:

```
std::map<int, ValueClass> value_classes = populate();
```

But then, this class has a virtual destructor, which means that you want actually may actually be a `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<ValueClass>>` and not a map of actual objects (not sure what these objects are going to be used for?).

Edit after the question edit:

In this case, Barry`s suggestion is the one to follow, using`emplace`:

```
std::map<int, ValueClass> populate()
{
    std::map<int, ValueClass> value_classes;
    value_classes.emplace(1, 5);
    return value_classes;
}
```

Also include `functional`.

Comment: Thank you for very fast and informative answer. I've updated my question with the code showing the real life application. `insert_or_assign` did not help it to compile either.

Comment: I get `C2660 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair': function does not take 2 arguments` with your integration of Barry`s suggestion :(

Comment: I would suggest you change your special class to remove the usage of emplace. Barry's code or mine work for your case, just create an actual function. Also, you have a big bug in your code, as the reference_wrapper points to a temporary that is destroyed.

Comment: You're right. I edited question and fixed reference_wrapper to not distract other readers (it's unique_ptr now). How do you mean that I create an actual function? I tried both and they fail to compile. With your solution I get 5 different errors on "insert_or_assign" line (make_map_by_moving not included, I tested in a separate project). I compile with MSVC https://godbolt.org/z/4RhuID

Answer (score 3):

You simply can not use `initializer_list` to `move` an object from a `non-copyable` object.

Your class deletes the `copy constructor` & `assignment operator`. When you try to initialize your `map` or any other `container` with an `initializer_list` the `initializer_list` strictly forces you to reference an `LValue` and forbids `RValue` move or forward semantics.

Here is a very nice blog article that explains all of the details: [knatten.org](https://blog.knatten.org/2018/10/05/why-you-cant-list-initialize-containers-of-non-copyable-types/) as well as a similar Q/A found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231351/initializer-list-constructing-a-vector-of-noncopyable-but-movable-objects).