# When is a copy constructor called in C++? - Function return

Tags: c++, scope, copy, stack, return

I'm working through chapter 18 of Stroustrup's Principles and Practice and am stuck on one part related to copy constructors.

I have a copy constructor defined as:

```
X(const X& x) {
    out("X(X&)");
    val = x.val;
}
```

X is a struct.
val is just an int value of X.
'out' is:

```
void out(const string& s) {
    cerr << this << "->" << s << ": " << val << "\n";
}
```

I also have the following 2 functions defined:

```
X copy(X a) {
    return a;
}
```

and

```
X copy2(X a) {
    X aa = a;
    return aa;
}
```

In main I have:

```
X loc(4);
X loc2 = loc;
loc2 = copy(loc);
loc2 = copy2(loc);
```

When I just call copy, the copy constructor is called twice: once for copy's parameter scope and once for the return call. This makes sense to me.

However, when I call copy2, the copy constructor is still just called twice: once for the function argument and once for 'X aa = a.' Why isn't it also called for the return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that copy constructors will be called in C++. In the case of return, it's likely to be replaced by a move or completely elided.

See also: [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning a local variable, move semantics apply.

Optimizations make copying, moving and returning even more elaborate, see Tatuyuki Ishi's answer.

[Here are some good examples for move semantics for return statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986802/1661064).