# Return string vs Passing string by reference to update the value

Tags: c++, stdstring, c++98

What will be good programming practice out of two below funcs:

1. This:

   ```
   std::string buildvalue(const std::string &in) {
       std::string out;
       out = // Do some calulation bases on input
       return out;
   }
   ```
2. Or this:

   ```
   void buildvalue(const std::string &in, std::string &out) {
       out = // Do some calulation bases on input
   }
   ```

Cautious with 2 function is that the caller may pass non-empty string. Is there any points to note.

Comment: 1 (this must be at least 16 chars long :) )

Comment: Both have some advantages and disadvantages which are worth considering in specific contexts

Comment: Return-value optimizations (especially copy-elision) and move semantics plays a big part making 1 a very good solution.

Comment: A user passing a non-empty string to `out` is no different from a user assigning the result of the first solution to a non-empty string. I don't see why one has to be extra cautious about it.

Comment: Unless you have to return multiple values, and even then you can get away without out parameters, you should return the output of the function.

Comment: See Howard's answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement/4986802#4986802  Basically, in modern C++ #1 is considered _in general_ to be the best practice

Comment: I would go with 1).  I would only use output parameters if you need to return more than one item.  But this question boils down to your personal preference in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, compiler will be able to optimize return value. It will place return value in calling function. For example,

```
std::string foo(...) { ... }

// ...

std::string result = foo(...);
```

Compiler will place foo return value right on the result spot.
It relieves us from reference argument and premature variable declaring.
Slightly C++17:
Instead const std::string& you can use std::string_view. Its advantage is optional for creating temp std::string in following case:

```
void foo(const std::string&);
// ...
foo("hello world"); // here will be create std::string object
```

With std::string_view (c++17)

```
void foo(std::string_view);
// ...
foo("hello world"); // more productive
```

+ std::string have operator std::string_view, that leads its to std::string_view

Comment: Thanks for your view, plus I am still using 98 version.

Comment: @PURVESHPATEL You may want to tag your question [tag:c++-98] - that's very relevant information.