# Return an object with std::move and chain the function

Tags: c++, chaining, stdmove

I made a method that returns an object in that way:

```
MyObject && 
MyController::getMyObject (const otherObject & options) const
{
    MyObject tmp;

    tmp.doSometing(options);

    return std::move(tmp);
}
```

Later in my code, I wanted to use that method with chained calls like this :

```
controller.getMyObject(options).doAnotherThing();
```

And it doesn't work, the call to "doAnotherThing" relies on an empty object. I know how to fix the situation :

```
auto tmp = controller.getMyObject(options);

tmp.doAnOtherThing();
```

My questions are : 
In the first place, is the method written correctly ?
How can I avoid to write the second way for the usage ? It's really ulgy...

Note: "MyObject" is movable.

Comment: Basically a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).  TL;DR: **Never** return a pointer or reference to a non-static function local variable.

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the first place, is the method written correctly ?

No. The function returns a dangling reference.

Both the first and the second usages have undefined behaviour.

A correct way, and probably what you inteded is to return an object, rather than a reference:

```
MyObject
MyController::getMyObject (const otherObject & options) const
{
    MyObject tmp;
    tmp.doSometing(options);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I will use your solution.

Answer (score 2):

> In the first place, is the method written correctly ?

Nope. You return a reference to an object that has gone out-of-scope.

> How can I avoid to write the second way for the usage ?

Return by value.

```
MyObject 
MyController::getMyObject (const otherObject & options) const
{
    MyObject tmp;

    tmp.doSometing(options);

    return tmp;
}
```

The above will behave in one of two ways due to how N/RVO is setup in C++. Either `tmp` will be elided and `getMyObject` operates on the result object directly. Or the result object is constructed by moving `tmp`. Either way, you get a valid object to use for method chaining.