# How to call the seed_seq constructor of a random generator from a member initialization list?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, std

I have a class with a `std::mersenne_twister_engine` member that I want to initialize with a `std::seed_seq` constructed from a string. Initially I tried this:

```
class A
{
private:
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
public:
    A(std::string seed) : rng(std::seed_seq(seed.begin(), seed.end())) { }
};
```

But that doesn't compile, because:

```
(...) cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::seed_seq' to '_Seed_seq &'
```

I can get it to work like this:

```
class B
{
private:
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
public:
    B(std::string seed) {
        std::seed_seq seedSeq(seed.begin(), seed.end());
        rng = std::mt19937_64(seedSeq);
    }
};
```

But if I understand correctly, the member variable `rng` will now be constructed twice, so if possible, I'd like to avoid that. **So, my main question is:** Is it possible to make this work without initializing `rng` twice?

Before anyone suggests, I've also tried using a separate member function to construct the `std::seed_seq` object, but the only way I can get it to compile is by returning a const ref like this:

```
class C
{
private:
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    const std::seed_seq& makeSeedSeq(std::string seed)
    {
        return std::seed_seq(seed.begin(), seed.end());
    }
public:
    C(std::string seed) : rng(makeSeedSeq(seed)) { }
};
```

Class `C` does compile, but when testing with different strings, the results are always the same and always as if the seed was an empty string. I guess this is because `makeSeedSeq` returns a reference to a local and the result is undefined behavior? **This is an aside**, but if someone could explain this and perhaps why `std::seed_seq` was implemented this way, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: For your class `C`, have a look at the first comment of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement). Citation: "Please do not return local variables by reference, _ever_. [..] – [fredoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252000/fredoverflow)"

Comment: @Michiel: I was mainly just trying to get something to compile there and I thought a dangling reference might be a problem, hence my guess that the unexpected result was undefined behavior caused by exactly that. However, I also remember reading that the lifetime of a temporary object is extended to the lifetime of a const reference to it. I'm not sure if that applies here or not, but if so, this might be valid code after all. Hence the question mark. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `std::seed_seq` variable to the class before `std::mt19937_64` (variables initialization order is important):

```
class A
{
private:
    std::seed_seq seed_seq;
    std::mt19937_64 rng;

public:
    A(std::string const& seed)
        : seed_seq(seed.begin(), seed.end())
        , rng(seed_seq)
    {}

    std::uint32_t uniform()
    {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint32_t>()(rng);
    }
};
```

Also I'd suggest to use `const&` in the constructor to avoid `std::string` copy constructor execution.