# How to properly call the vulkan.hpp constructor for command buffers?

Tags: c++, resources, gpu, vulkan, raii

I have been changing some vulkan code to use the vulkan.hpp structures and methods.

Since I like RAIIs, I am using the Unique wrappers, to not have to explicitely handle resource management.

So far I have been able to create 2 versions of each wrapping method I am making, one version creates a non unique object, and another method calls the first and then initializes a unique handle from the first. Example:

```
vector<vk::UniqueFramebuffer> CreateFramebuffersUnique(vk::SurfaceKHR surface,
    vk::PhysicalDevice phys_device, vk::Device device, vk::RenderPass render_pass,
    vector<vk::ImageView> image_views)
{
    auto framebuffers =
        CreateFramebuffers(surface, phys_device, device, render_pass, image_views);
    vector<vk::UniqueFramebuffer> u_framebuffers;
    for(auto &fb : framebuffers)
        u_framebuffers.push_back(vk::UniqueFramebuffer(fb, device));

    return u_framebuffers;
}
```

The above method creates an array of framebuffers and then re-initializes each framebuffer as a unique framebuffer prior of returning it.

I tried doing the same with command buffers:

```
vector<vk::UniqueCommandBuffer> CreateCommandBuffersUnique(vk::SurfaceKHR &surface,
    vk::PhysicalDevice &phys_device, vk::Device &device, vk::RenderPass &render_pass,
    vk::Pipeline &graphics_pipeline, vk::CommandPool &command_pool,
    vector<vk::Framebuffer> &framebuffers)
{
    auto command_buffers = CreateCommandBuffers(surface, phys_device, device, render_pass,
        graphics_pipeline, command_pool, framebuffers);

    vector<vk::UniqueCommandBuffer> u_command_buffers;
    for(auto &cb : command_buffers)
        u_command_buffers.push_back(vk::UniqueCommandBuffer(cb, device));

    return u_command_buffers;
}
```

The above technically works, but upon program termination, the validation layers complain about a mistake upon resorce de allocation:

```
validation layer: vkFreeCommandBuffers: required parameter commandPool specified as VK_NULL_HANDLE
UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-RequiredParameter
4096
validation layer: Invalid CommandPool Object 0x0. The Vulkan spec states: commandPool must be a valid VkCommandPool handle (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-commandPool-parameter)
VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-commandPool-parameter
```

This happens because the command pool field of the unique handle is not set properly:

```
(gdb) p t_command_buffers[0]
$6 = {<vk::PoolFree<vk::Device, vk::CommandPool, vk::DispatchLoaderStatic>> = {m_owner = {m_device = 0x555555ec14e0}, m_pool = {m_commandPool = 0x0},
    m_dispatch = 0x7fffffffe2f7}, m_value = {m_commandBuffer = 0x555555fe6390}}
```

I checked, and although there is a commandBuffer.getPool(), there is no setPool().

Any suggestions on properly setting the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the source or the signature of the `CreateCommandBuffers` function you're calling internally from `CreateCommandBuffersUnique`.  However, lets assume it returns a type of `std::vector<vk::CommandBuffer>`

It looks like you're then looping over those and wrapping them manually in `vk::UniqueCommandBuffer` instances.  However, you're passing the cb (assumed here to be a `vk::CommandBuffer` and a `vk::Device` to the `UniqueCommandBuffer` constructor here

```
u_command_buffers.push_back(vk::UniqueCommandBuffer(cb, device));
```

<s>I'm actually not clear on how that even compiles, unless `vk::Device` has an `operator ()()`.  Regardless, the second parameter to a `vk::UniqueCommandBuffer` should be a deleter object.</s>

So it turns out that all of the `UniqueXXX` types derive from `UniqueHandle<>`, which in turn derives from `UniqueHandleTraits<...>` which is specialized for each type, in order to give it a default `deleter` type.  Most of the `UniqueHandleTraits<...>` specializations use an `ObjectDestroy<...>` template because most objects only need their creating `Device` to destroy them.  However, the `UniqueHandleTraits<CommandBuffer>` and `UniqueHandleTraits<DescriptorSet>` specializations use `PoolFree<...>` for their deleters.

Therefore, your use of

```
vk::UniqueCommandBuffer(cb, device));
```

implicitly turns into

```
vk::UniqueCommandBuffer(cb, 
    vk::PoolFree<Device, CommandPool,Dispatch> { device, {}, {} }
)
```

That `{}` after `device` is where the pool is supposed to be specified.

See the corresponding code from `vk::Device::allocateCommandBuffersUnique`

```
PoolFree<Device,CommandPool,Dispatch> deleter( *this, allocateInfo.commandPool, d );
for ( size_t i=0 ; i<allocateInfo.commandBufferCount ; i++ )
{
  commandBuffers.push_back( UniqueCommandBuffer( buffer[i], deleter ) );
}
```

To fix your code you either need to use `vk::Device::allocateCommandBuffersUnique` or replicate it's behavior, specifically create a *deleter* object or lambda and pass it as the second parameter to the `UniqueCommandBuffer` ctor.

Based on my examination of the `UniqueHandleTraits`, it looks like you'd be able to fix your code just by changing this line:

```
    u_framebuffers.push_back(vk::UniqueFramebuffer(fb, device));
```

to

```
    u_framebuffers.push_back(vk::UniqueFramebuffer(fb, { device, command_pool }));
```

Comment: The above syntax not only compiles but works for almost all objects (I used it for swap chains, devices, framebuffers, commandpool... the only object it didn;t work on was CommandBuffers), I will append a temptative solution that fixes the problem, at least for now.

But you are correct about the types of the return values of each function

Comment: The other types you mention aren't allocated from a pool.  In fact if you look at vulkan.hpp and search for `UniqueHandleTraits<CommandBuffer,Dispatch>` you'll see that most of vulkan types have specialized deleters based on `ObjectDestroy` but pool allocated resources like `CommandBuffer` and `DescriptorSet` use a deleter specializations based on `PoolFree`.  It looks like the reason your code even compiles is that `PoolFree` has default arguments for everyhing in it's ctor, so your code essentially calls `PoolFree<Device, CommandPool, ...> instance(device, {}, {})`

Answer (score 0):

Upon playing around I have found a solution that solves the issue, although I would prefer doing things more closely to the example I provided with framebuffers:

```
vector<vk::UniqueCommandBuffer> CreateCommandBuffersUnique(vk::SurfaceKHR &surface,
    vk::PhysicalDevice &phys_device, vk::Device &device, vk::RenderPass &render_pass,
    vk::Pipeline &graphics_pipeline, vk::CommandPool &command_pool,
    vector<vk::Framebuffer> &framebuffers)
{
    vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info(command_pool,
        vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary, framebuffers.size());
    auto[result, u_command_buffers] = device.allocateCommandBuffersUnique(alloc_info);
    if (result != vk::Result::eSuccess)
        Log::RecordLogError("Failed to allocate command buffers!");

    auto command_buffers = CreateCommandBuffers(surface, phys_device, device, render_pass,
        graphics_pipeline, command_pool, framebuffers);

    for(auto &cb : command_buffers)
    {
        u_command_buffers[&cb - &command_buffers[0]].reset(cb);
    }

    return std::move(u_command_buffers);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::move` here.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement/4986802#4986802

Comment: How can I prevent the constructor from being called in that case? i.e how do I extend the life of the unique handle?