# Why capturing return value in rvalue reference has more assembly instructions than capturing it by value in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, arm, c++14

I was reading [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement/4986802#4986802) question and found that best practice is to return by a value. so I ran below two examples in godbolt with ARM gcc 10.2(linux) compiler to get assembly instructions for both

1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> return_vector(void)
{
    std::vector<int> tmp {1,2,3,4,5};
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> && rval_ref = return_vector();
   while(1){}
  return 0;
}
```

2. Almost same but without `&&`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> return_vector(void)
{
    std::vector<int> tmp {1,2,3,4,5};
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int>  rval_ref = return_vector();
   while(1){}
  return 0;
}
```

now code with rvalue `&&` has more instructions compared to code without rvalue reference. shouldn't they be same ?

Below are extra assembly instructions for code with rvalue reference
(left is code with rvalue ref `&&` and right is code without it.)

[image]

Comment: What optimization options are you using?

Comment: I didn't use any explicit optimisation option.

Comment: Then that's your problem right there.  Without optimization it is very common for a compiler to emit unnecessary code, or to fail to notice that two "obviously" equivalent pieces of code are actually the same.  In fact, it looks to me like with `-O2` you do get identical code in `main()` for both versions.

Comment: Yeah you are right about it. Thank you.

Comment: Would probably be more interesting to look at a case where the callee can't just inline and optimize away, and where you use the result.  (e.g. return one element of the vector, like `int foo() { tmp = bar(); return tmp[1]; }`.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  Oh, that's identical, too.  https://godbolt.org/z/5bGcnboxh