# why does an external function that takes a class object as a parameter calls a move constructor when it returns the same object

Tags: c++, oop, move-constructor

hey guys am still learning c++ but am just kind of confused about move constructors and copy constructors.

first i have a simple function that set a value to an object

```
#include <iostream>
#include "item.hpp"
#include "player.hpp"

player giveHealth(player user, int value) {
    user.set_health(value);
    return user;
}

int main() {
    player a;
    player b(a);
    
    a = giveHealth(a, 100);
    
    return 0;
}
```

as you see i didnt add && on the return type but it still call's the move constructor at the end of the givehealth() function?

Comment: When you are returning local objects from function, move constructor is called automatically (unless (N)RVO kicks in, and no copies are made at all).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 rvalues and move semantics confusion (return statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement)

Comment: @SergeyA what confuse me is why move constructor is called unstead of copy constructor, like i guess the move constructor is called when u declare the return type with reference symbole (&&), isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as you see i didnt add && on the return type

&& would make the return type a reference. If you were to return a reference, then there wouldn't be a move. But you'd be returning a reference to a local variable which would have been destroyed at the end of the function and as such the returned reference would always be danging. Don't do that.

Although `user` in `return user;` is an lvalue, and as such you might expect there to be a copy, this is a special case where because `user` is a local variable, the move constructor is used instead. This language rule is possible, because the local variable is about to be destroyed, and thus it is safe to be moved from.

Comment: yeah i got it, thank you for that explication, but why did the move constructor got called unstead of copy constructor

Comment: @KiasMohamedIslam I've explained that in the second paragraph.

Comment: thank you soo much i got it now i really appreaciate that

Answer (score 0):

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) under "Automatic move from local variables and parameters".

The compiler does that.

> If expression ... variable ... is declared
> as a parameter of
> the innermost enclosing function...
> then overload resolution to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value ... is performed twice:
> first as if expression were an rvalue expression (thus **it may select the move constructor**),

Colloquially, the `return variable;` is automatically turned into `return std::move(variable);`.

Comment: I don't really like that simplification as it masks the true reason. In OP's code, `user` is an eXpirering value (xvalue) and xvalues do bind to rvalue references (`&&`). Per design, the move constructor is preferred over the copy constructor when both could apply.

Comment: @YSC `user` is not an xvalue. It is an lvalue. JDługosz's simplification is nearly identical with your explanation given that `std::move(variable)` would be an xvalue. But if either your or their explanation were exactly accurate, then `return user;` wouldn't work with a type that has a deleted move constructor and non-deleted copy constructor... but it works.