# Is it possible to use return value move semantics with a protected copy constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, cgal

I am using the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) library and writing a function that I hope to use move semantics [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement/4986802#4986802):

```cpp
PointTree preparePointTree(const vector<PlyPoint>& pointCloud) {
  PointTree tree;
  kd_tree::prepare<...>(pointCloud, tree);
  return tree;
}
```

and I'm calling it like:

```cpp
PointTree tree = preparePointTree(pointCloud);
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile; GCC complains that:

```cpp
return tree;  // <-- error: 'CGAL::Kd_tree<...>' is private within this context
```

with note:

```cpp
private:
  // protected copy constructor
  Kd_tree(const Tree& tree)   // <-- note: declared private here
```

which is from [this code](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/8c9fc331cd0e523f897f830da480483b6fb70d5d/Spatial_searching/include/CGAL/Kd_tree.h#L139-L140).

So the issue seems to be that returning `tree` is illegal if the copy-constructor is unavailable, even though I don't want to copy, but to move.

I suppose that's because because move semantics depend on the call site (the call to `preparePointTree()`), and the function implementation by itself is treated as "has to compile even in the non-move case".

So, what now?

Is there something that I, or the CGAL library, can do to allow moving but not copying?

What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Can you pass the return value in as a second argument and do an explicit move?

Comment: But the `kd_tree` doesn't support moving at all. Wrap it via `unique_ptr` or something.

Comment: *"even though I don't want to copy, but to move"* - it does try to move. But there is no move constructor provided by `Kd_tree`, and its automatic generation is inhibited by the user-declared copy c'tor. This class is not meant to be passed around as it seems. Try indirection.

Comment: i suppose the actual error message doesnt say " error: 'CGAL::Kd_tree<...>' is private within this context" but rather `CGAL::Kd_tree<...>(CGAL::Kd_tree&)` or similar

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are correct, expanding my shortening, it is `CGAL::Kd_tree<...>::Kd_tree(const Tree&) [with ...2000 more chars...]`.

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference on move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators;
> - there is no user-declared destructor.
>
> then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&).

The `Kd_tree` class provides a user-declared copy constructor, so it doesn't get a move constructor automatically. Since it doesn't have a move constructor you cannot move it.

Comment: You can "move" things without a move c'tor. The copy c'tor can serve that purpose. But it must be accessible.

Comment: What do you mean by "move" things (in quotes)? (N)RVO, which just elides the copy/move altogether?

Comment: @Kevin a move of something that cannot move but can copy is just a copy

Comment: The provision of a return statement returning a local is to first treat it as an rvalue, then (if overload resolution fails) treat it as an lvalue. This always happens, regardless of NRVO. The const reference of the copy c'tor can bind to an rvalue, and so it will be used when no move c'tor is generated. Hence the quotes. It's moved successfully, but by copying.