# Getting Unexpected output in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function which creates an array and return a pointer of the array:
Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int* example() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    int *a = arr;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int *a = example();
    cout << *a     << endl;
    cout << *(a+1) << endl;
    cout << *(a+2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
1
1878006336
3
```

I don't know why am I getting that garbage value at 2nd line instead of 2.

Here are some of my observations regarding this:

1. I am getting desired output if I manually create the array and pointer in the main() function.
2. If I print the second line before the first line, I get desired output as:

```
2
1
3
```

What is the reason behind this weird behaviour?

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior* by dereferencing an address from an object (`arr` in `example`) that has long-since expired once the call to the function returns. The address held in `a` post-function-call is worthless.

Comment: Please don't tag questions as both C and C++ unless your question is explicitly about the differences of both languages. Often enough the C++ answer to something is rather different than the C answer.

Comment: Answers below, but you need to understand the concept of *lifetime*. All objects have a lifetime and using them after their life has ended is a bug. In your case the lifetime of `arr` ends when the `example` exits. The fact that you returned a pointer to the array  does not make any difference. This kind of pointer is known as a *dangling pointer*,

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042552/returning-a-pointer-of-a-local-variable-c), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer) and [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943680/return-an-array-without-getting-a-dangling-pointer-as-result-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `arr` is declared local to the function. As a result its *lifetime* ends when the function exits. We call this automatic lifetime. Returning a pointer to this memory invokes undefined behavior. The code might work the way you expect, or it might not.

To work around this, you need a lifetime that is not automatic, and which can be controlled. There are a few paths to this.

### Manual memory management

You might use dynamic memory management with `new` and `delete` (or in this case `delete []`). This is generally discouraged as it creates many opportunities for mistakes.

```
int *example() {
    int *a = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

    return a;
}
```

You would need to remember to delete this array.

```
int main() {
    int *a = example();

    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << a[1] << endl;
    cout << a[2] << endl;

    delete[] a;

    return 0;
}
```

### Smart pointers

You could use a smart pointer, which makes explicitly deallocating unnecessary, as the memory it points to is deallocated when the smart pointer goes out of scope.

```
unique_ptr<int[]> example() {
    auto a = unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 });

    return a;
}

int main() {
    auto a = example();

    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << a[1] << endl;
    cout << a[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### STL containers

The most idiomatic approach is to use an STL container class.

The `std::array` container maps directly to the fixed size arrays seen so far. The `std::vector` container is more appropriate if the size is unknown at compile time, which it *often* will be, making this a very common container to see in idiomatic C++ code.

As with the smart pointer, the memory does not have automatic storage duration, so it can live beyond the scope in which it's declared, and the data is deallocated when the container goes out of scope.

```
array<int, 3> example() {
    array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };

    return a;
}

int main() {
    auto a = example();

    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << a[1] << endl;
    cout << a[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...or `<vector>`, which really should be the go-to container of choice. If you add that, I'd happily remove my answer for your more elaborate one.

Comment: Finished that edit before I loaded your comment. Great minds think alike (or at least small minds seldom differ).

Answer (score -2):

Your function is allocating array in the local scope/stack, it won't be available for the outside caller. Allocate the array using new operator for C++, and `malloc()` for C, and then that pointer will be valid for the caller function.

Comment: Question is tagged C++, which makes `malloc` the wrong answer to basically *anything*. ;-) Even if you change that to `new`, allocating memory in a function and expect the caller to call `delete` is bad design (should be a smart pointer, or at the very least a class with `new` in the constructor and `delete` in the destructor).

Answer (score -2):

arr[] is a local variable, it is stored on the stack, its content might not be preserved after the example() function has returned.

Here are 2 examples that can get the behavior that you want:

Example 1: Store array in global region

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int arr[] = {1,2,3};

int* example(){
    int* a = arr;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int* a = example();
    cout<<*a<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+1)<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example 2: Store array in heap region

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int* example(){
    int* arr = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    int* a = arr;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int* a = example();
    cout<<*a<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+1)<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+2)<<endl;
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best not to mix C dynamic memory management into C++ code.

Comment: Same as for Anand's answer: `malloc` in a C++ program is a bad idea. Allocating memory dynamically in a function and passing out an owning pointer is a bad idea. `<cstdlib.h>` is plain wrong.

Comment: If that's the reason, then why is it giving correct values when I tried to print second line before the first? It's data should be deleted and it should give garbage values at all the three lines.

Comment: @HarshBansal the data "might" be deleted and give garbage value, not "must"

Comment: @HarshBansal The beauty of undefined behavior: It's *undefined*, which might include "apparently correct" behavior under certain circumstances.

Comment: Aside from the `malloc` and `free` nonsense, I would suggest A. not perpetuating the lack of whitespace from the question in your answer, and B. not using `*(a+n)` when `a[n]` is available.

Comment: @HarshBansal *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."*