# How the vector gets returned even though it is a local variable inside a method of a class

Tags: c++, vector, stl

The `vector<int> bfs` is local to the method bfs_of_graph then how can we return the vector as it would be erased in the memory and only garbage values should be printed in the calling method. But I find the values are present. How ?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> bfs_of_graph(int no_of_nodes, vector<int> adj_list[]) {
        queue<int> qt;
        vector<int> bfs;
        vector<int> visited(no_of_nodes + 1, 0);
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_nodes; ++i) {
            // Node in graph not visited
            if (visited[i] == 0) {
                qt.push(i); 
                visited[i] = 1;
                while (!qt.empty()) {
                    int node = qt.front(); 
                    qt.pop();
                    bfs.push_back(node);
                    
                    for (auto ele: adj_list[node]) {
                        if (visited[ele] == 0) {
                            qt.push(ele);
                            visited[ele] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        return bfs;
    }
};
```

Comment: Originally it returned a copy of the local. This copy is actually usually avoided, either by an optimization called RVO or copy-elision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), or by using move semantics (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics).

Answer (score 2):

Until C++11, the basic behavior according to the standard was to invoke the **copy constructor** of the returned object (`vector<int>` in your case). However, according to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), some compilers and optimizers applied the [**copy-elision** optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) (also known as RVO).

C++11 introduced **move semantics**. In some cases, local objects can be moved into the caller's object. You can see here for more info: [C++11 rvalues and move semantics confusion (return statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement). Some compilers and optimizers still continued to use the **copy-elision** optimization when appropriate.

C++17 introduced **guaranteed copy-elision** in certain cases. See here: [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work).

**The bottom line**: even without any modern C++ stuff, the code you mentioned can work by creating a copy of the local object (thus constructing the object on the caller side). But nowadays, usually there will be no copy (either a move, or copy-elision all the way).

Answer (score 1):

If you just look at it then you see that the return type is `vector<int>`. It's not a pointer nor a reference. The vector is returned as value. Which means it gets copied.

Copied to where? Say you have the following:

```
std::vector<int> v = bfs_of_graph(...);
```

Internally the compiler places `v` on the stack in passes the address of `v` in the *structure return register*. The return statement would then copy the temporary `bfs` into the object pointer to by the *structure return register*.

This is how it used to be. But over time people noticed that this can be rather slow and wanted to get rid of the extra copy on return and that is now possible in modern C++.

One of the ways the standard specified that is RVO (return value optimization) ([Copy_elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). This is what the compiler will use in your example. There is only a single `return bfs;` so when you declare `vector<int> bfs;` at the start of the function that doesn't actually create a new object. Instead the compiler uses the object from the *structure return register* in place of bfs. So the function will modify the `v` from the caller directly and never have a temporary for `bfs` at al.

In cases where this is not possible there is another mechanism that at least reduces the cost of copying called [move semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics). For a `vector` move semantic means that the destination vector will take over the data part of the source vector. So it only copies the size, capacity and data pointer, which takes constant time. None of the data (on the heap) itself is copied.