# return C++ local string to another function

Tags: c++, string, function, memory, scope

Here is my confusion. I think `s1` and `s2` are function local object instance of type `string`, we should not return function local scope object to outside. But it seems below code works, wondering why?

```
vector<string> testString(){
    vector<string> result;
    string s1 = "123";
    string s2 = "456";
    result.push_back(s1);
    result.push_back(s2);

    return result;
}

void testStringWrapper(){
    vector<string> result = testString();
    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        cout << result[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are free to copy (or logically copy) objects. Returning a *reference* or *pointer* to a local variable is something else.

Comment: Your  code doesn't return `s1` or `s2`. What do you feel is a problem here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think when we call push_back, we make a copy of `s1` and `s2`, but `result` defined in `testString ` is local object, it is ok to be used outside in `testStringWrapper `?

Comment: The function returns a copy of `result`, not `result` itself.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, thanks. My concern is, if C++ runtime clears local object, is there an issue?

Comment: Even though `result` is local, when you return, you return a copy of `result`, or a "moved" version of `result` and everything inside it. See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I see, and copy of vector triggers another full copy string object?

Comment: Well, here `result` is moved, not copied - essentially, a new `vector` is created and takes over the internal data previously managed by `result`, leaving it empty. So strings are actually copied only once (and you can avoid that copy by writing `result.push_back(std::move(s1));` )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why it is OK to return vector from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655059/why-it-is-ok-to-return-vector-from-function)

Answer (score 4):

You return nothing by reference or pointer, you return by value -- which is acceptable.  Copies/moves are performed as required.

```
vector<string> testString(){
    // Declares a vector that will be returned:
    vector<string> result;

    // Creates two local strings:
    string s1 = "123";
    string s2 = "456";

    // *Copies* the local strings into the vector *by value*:
    result.push_back(s1);
    result.push_back(s2);

    // Returns the vector *by value*.  A copy might be made, but NVRO will elide it.
    return result;
}
```

The `vector<string>` contains copies of the strings from the function locals.

This can be made more efficient by *moving* the strings into the vector, which "pilfers" the data pointer from the source string object, leaving it in an unspecified-but-valid state:

```
// Instead of:
// result.push_back(s1);
// result.push_back(s2);

// Move the strings:
result.emplace_back(std::move(s1));
result.emplace_back(std::move(s2));
```

Then no copy is made, and `s1` and `s2` no longer contain their respective values -- the vector stole the contents.

Comment: Thanks cdhowie, I think if I return reference like  `vector<string>&`, there will be an issue, correct?

Comment: "Copies/moves are performed as required".. or not performed as required in '17

Comment: @LinMa yes, that would be bad

Comment: Return by reference could "potentially" be bad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil

Comment: Thanks for the update cdhowie, it is very smart. Mark as answer.

Comment: @Tuan333 in this case it *would* be bad.

Comment: @xaxxon agreed.

Comment: I think the `emplace_back` isn't necessary, as the move-copy constructor will be called anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not strictly necessary, but it's not harmful either. Generally, there's little reason *not* to use `emplace_back`. It should be what you use by default.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning values, so they're copied or moved over to the call site. That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
vector<string> testString(){
    vector<string> result;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

you create a vector `result` at local scope, but just before the function gets out of scope, you return it and the critical part is that the return type of your function is `vector<string>`, which **copies** `result` and returns it to the caller of the function, which assigned it to a brand new value, in your case:

```
 vector<string> result = testString();
```

but don't be confused by the same name of `result` in `testString()` scope and in `testStringWrapper()` scope.

These two `result` vector are different objects in memory. It would be equivalent with having this for example `vector<string> foo = testString();`.

---

> we should not return function local scope object to outside

True in some cases.

This applies when *returning by reference or a pointer*. In that case, you would have something like this:

```
// BAD PRACTICE
vector<string>& testString(){
    vector<string> result;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

and you would return a reference to an object that would go out of scope as soon as the function terminated. So when you would try to access it outside of `testString()`, you would access memory that has gone out of scope.

A typical solution to this problem is to dynamically allocate memory for your object with `new`, return it by reference and then manage the memory yourself (with that said, the memory will not be de-allocated until you call `delete` on it).