# C++ understanding RVO (as compared to returning local variable reference)

Tags: c++, c++11

It's my first year of using C++ and learning on the way. I'm currently reading up on Return Value Optimizations (I use C++11 btw). E.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization, and immediately these beginner examples with primitive types spring to mind:

```
int& func1()
{
    int i = 1;
    return i;
} 
//error, 'i' was declared with automatic storage (in practice on the stack(?)) 
//and is undefined by the time function returns
```

...and this one:

```
int func1()
{
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
//perfectly fine, 'i' is copied... (to previous stack frame... right?)
```

Now, I get to this and try to understand it in the light of the other two:

```
Simpleclass func1()
{
    return Simpleclass();
}
```

What actually happens here? I know most compilers will optimise this, what I am asking is not 'if' but:

- how the optimisation works (the accepted response)
- does it interfere with storage duration: stack/heap (<strike>Old: Is it basically random whether I've copied from stack or created on heap and moved (passed the reference)? Does it depend on created object size?</strike>)
- is it not better to use, say, explicit `std::move`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does return statement copy values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529447/does-return-statement-copy-values)

Comment: _Is it basically random whether I've copied from stack or created on heap_ No, it is created on stack.

Comment: Why would the heap be involved? Implementation is explained pretty well in the article you linked.

Comment: I get the gist of n. r. v. optimisation now. As for why I wrote 'heap', I was under the impression that larger objects don't fit on the stack, and this is also why it is called 'automatic storage' declaration. But maybe that's another thing I misunderstand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't see any effect of RVO when returning ints.

However, when returning large objects like this:

```
struct Huge { ... };

Huge makeHuge() {
    Huge h { x, y, x };
    h.doSomething();
    return h;
}
```

The following code...

```
auto h = makeHuge();
```

... after RVO would be implemented something like this (pseudo code) ...

```
h_storage = allocate_from_stack(sizeof(Huge));
makeHuge(addressof(h_storage));
auto& h = *properly_aligned(h_storage);
```

... and makeHuge would compile to something like this...

```
void makeHuge(Huge* h_storage) // in fact this address can be
                               // inferred from the stack pointer
                               // (or just 'known' when inlining).
{
    phuge = operator (h_storage) new Huge(x, y, z);
    phuge->doSomething(); 
}
```